# What's the relationship between $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}f(X_{1i},X_{2i})$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i}\sum_{j}f(X_{1i},X_{2j})$?

Tags: mean, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem

Suppose $(X_1,X_2)$ is a bivariate random vector following distribution $G$.  $f(x_1,x_2)$ is a known bivariate smooth function. Suppose we are interested in estimating $E[f(X_1,X_2)]$ using a random sample $\{(X_{11},X_{21})...(X_{1n},X_{2n})\}$.

I'm wondering what's the relationship between $\widehat{\alpha}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(X_{1i},X_{2i})$ and  $\widehat{\beta}=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f(X_{1i},X_{2j})$?

I'm particularly interested in if the following is true:

$\sqrt{n}(\widehat{\alpha}-E[f(X_1,X_2)])=\sqrt{n}(\widehat{\beta}-E[f(X_1,X_2)])+o_{p}(1)$?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks. This is helpful. So if X1 and X2 are independent, then this equation holds, right?

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the only case for an arbitrary $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite $\widehat{\beta}$ as
\begin{align*}\widehat{\beta}&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nf(X_{1i},X_{2j})\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\ne j}f(X_{1i},X_{2j})+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(X_{1i},X_{2i})\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\ne j}f(X_{1i},X_{2j})+\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}\hat\alpha}_{o_P(1)}
\end{align*}
Assuming the expectations
$$\mathbb{E}_{(X_1,X_2)}[f(X_1,X_2)]=\mu\qquad \mathbb{E}_{X_1}[\mathbb{E}_{X_2}[\{f(X_1,X_2)\}]=\mu_0$$
are defined, $\hat\alpha$ converges almost surely to $\mu$ and $\widehat{\beta}$ to $\mu⁰$ And similarly when CLTs apply.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful!

Comment: Can you clarify your definition of $\mathbb{E}_{X_1}[\mathbb{E}_{X_2}[ \{ f(X_1, X_2) \} ]$, since surely, $\mathbb{E}_{X_1} \mathbb{E}_{X_2|X_1} f(X_1, X_2) = \mathbb{E}_{X_1, X_2}  f(X_1, X_2)$?

Comment: I though it was clearly different: this double expectation is meant under the marginal distributions of $X_1$ and of $X_2$.

Comment: @Xi'an Hi, another question. What version of CLT shall we apply here to $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq j}(f(X_{1i},X_{2i})-\mu^{0})$? Seems it doesn't have the form as in standard Lindberg-Levy CLT.